# How the checkpoint in JBD2 is managed when kernel needs to free memory urgently?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, filesystems, ext4

I am diving into the ext4 and JBD2 source code and I did not understand clearly how a read operation is performed right after a transaction has been committed.

This is what I understood reading the source code:

1. transactions use ***buffer_head*** to store the metadata;
2. once a transaction commits, the **buffer_head** ptr is added to the checkpoint list;
3. checkpoint may not start right after the commit operation;
4. checkpoint is performed and the ***buffer_head*** can be freed from memory

I wonder if in between step 3 and 4 the kernel needs to free memory from some reason and, in my understanding, it is safe to free these ***buffer_head*** because we can read the transaction from the journal area on disk back to memory later.

**Q1)** I wonder if this situation of freeing the ***buffer_head*** is possible before checkpoint or not or if the ***buffer_head*** is locked in memory until the checkpoint evict them.

**Q2)** Also I am not sure about step 3, I could not find whether the checkpoint takes some time before executes or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Q1)** The `buffer_head` is not freed until the checkpoint is performed, because it is much more expensive freeing the buffer, then loading it back from disk to memory rather than keeping the `buffer_head` in memory to checkpoint in a short *delta* time.

**Q2)** Checkpoint can be delayed or can be performed before a commit due to no free blocks in journal area on disk, so checkpoint is started to release blocks to be used by the upcoming commit.